# Bender guru coffee issue

Tags: mesh, particles, normals, lighting, artifacts

[image: Bender guru coffee cup issue]

Hello everyone when rendering my coffee cup form the blender guru tutorial I run into this issue. I don't know if this is a lighting issue or if there is something wrong with my mesh. I tried resizing the liquid to match up with the glass. I have also checked and ensured my normals are facing the correct way (Blue).

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you identify the issue?

Comment: You will learn a lot if you re-watch the video and see what you did differently.

Comment: The issue are the texture at the bottom half of the glass. when I delete the plate it doesn't happen anymore so I'm assuming it's a light issue. or how the light passes through the glass and the liquid. @KOOKIREO